# Creating function

Tags: r, function

If I have data set named 'example' and it has 'id'variable.

I want to create function like this;

```
a<-function(data,variable){
work<-data[!duplicated(data$variable),]
work$obs<-c(1:length(work$variable))
work1<-merge.data.frame(data, work, by="variable")
}
a(data=example, variable=weight)
```

There is no warning message but it doesn't work.

'work' and 'work1' data set is not created.

When I run this code without function, it works.

Comment: A variable created in the function will only exist in the function, not in the global environment

Comment: return work and work1 from the function or lookup <<-

Comment: Do not use `<<-`. Learn functional programming instead.

Comment: @etienne How can I see 'work' data set in the global environment?

Comment: Put `browser()` as the first line in your function, rerun the definition and run the function. You will be inside the function and you can explore what's going on.

Comment: You see the `work` dataset in global environment, if no such variable exists inside your function, by default (see lexical scoping rules of R).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that `work` and `work1` only exist in your function. You need to set it globally for it to exist outside. Try:

```
a<-function(data,variable){
    work<<-data[!duplicated(data$variable),]
    work$obs<-c(1:length(work$variable))
    work1<<-merge.data.frame(data, work, by="variable")
}
a(data=example, variable=weight)
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing this as every time you run your function you will overwrite `work` and `work1` in your environment. Consider returning something and using this to overwrite your variables.

Comment: Even with your examples, neither `work` and `work1` will exist outside the function.

Comment: They will be returned outside the function but not assigned to anything, you can just set the result of the function to a variable?

Comment: No, they won't be returned outside, except if you use `assign` inside the function.

Comment: You mean `b<-function(x){ x<-1; x }` I guess. Do you see `x` in your clean environment after running `b(1)`?

Comment: Well, no. I assumed he just wanted to return something rather than set the variable within the function.

Comment: No, OP wants `work` and `work1` to be returned in the global environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96964/discussion-between-jcollerton-and-pascal).

Comment: Don't use `<<-` it is bad habit. Use `assign`.